# Keep users from accessing pages in Rails app if they're not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to Rails and am building a webapp to learn. I currently have the webapp working to accept new users and log them in. However, I want to block access to pages other than the login page when users aren't logged in. I've searched for hours and nothing I have found has worked. I don't want to use to Devise. Here is my code:

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery
   include SessionsHelper
   before_action :logged_in_user
end
```

Session Helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
      !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
     unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to 'name of login page'
     end
  end

end
```

Currently, the page just reloads over and over (because the user isn't logged in) and the page times out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `before_action` in the `ApplicationController` the specified action will run before any action in all controller that inherits `ApplicationController` unless you skip it by `skip_before_action`.

In your case you need either to apply `before_action` in `ApplicationController` and use `skip_before_action` before `login` action in for example in the `SessionsController` or you can only use `before_action` in all other controllers instead of `ApplicationController` to specify when you need them to run.

```
class SessionsController
  skip_before_action :logged_in_user, only: :login

  def login
  end
end
```

> Also remember to handle when a user is already logged in and he tries
>   to visit the login page.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I tried adding skip_before_action :logged_in_user to my sessions and users controllers and it is still redirecting over and over. I can't add it to the pages controller, because some of the pages are needed to login and some are what I'm trying to protect. Is there a way to target some of the pages but not all of them?

Comment: yes, you can use only option with before action for example `before_action :do_sometihing, only: [:new, :create, :update]`